# Seaborn Catplot Confidence Intervals Appear on the X Axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a bunch of data generated from a game. The game generates three types of data:
Rewards, values and estimates. I use this data for the y axis.

The games have different action spaces, which I use for the x axis.

And the columns are determined by the type of reinforcement agent I used to generate the data (DDQN vs DQN).

The catplot seems to be correct, in so far that the points are in fact placed in the means of this data. When I load the dataFrame it looks like one would expect.

Problem is, that this is a plot with CI active. Obviously the CI has been put parallel to the x axis/vertically.

[image]

I did another run with some data that displayed this better, and it was confirmed, that this was the problem.

How would I go about fixing this?

CODE:

```
def make_Catplot(dataFrame):

    sns.set_theme(style="whitegrid")

    # Draw a pointplot to show pulse as a function of three categorical factors
    CatPole = sns.catplot(x="action_size", y="value", hue="value_type",col="DQN_type",
                    capsize=.2, palette="YlGnBu_d", height=6, aspect=.75,
                    kind="point", data=dataFrame)
    print("Catpole initialized")
    CatPole.despine(left=True)
    print("Catpole returned")
    return CatPole
```

[image: Snippet of the file I used for reproducability]

Comment: @JohanC The straight lines are a problem with my machine learning algorithm not learning correctly, not with the graph. If you zoom in on the estimate, you will see that there are horizontal bars. I do have some data, would you like for me to send it? If so, how?

Comment: Could you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70749114/edit) your post and add some simplified data (as text) that reproduce the problem?  The horizontal error bars might be just then end caps of the lines (similar to the end caps of a boxplot).  If the errors are so small, it's better to use `ci=None` (and maybe `capsize=0`; you might also test with a larger capsize to verify that these lines are indeed the end caps).

Comment: @JohanC Hello again, I have added a snippet of how the datafile is structured. I can't post the file I used to test my hypothesis, as this also contained thousands of rows. But essentially you could just repeat a sequence of floats in the range [0-2.5] following the structure of my datafile. Otherwise, I could upload the CSV if there is some way to share it through that.

Comment: There are two problems with your upload. First, it is an image instead of text. Second, it only shows 2 different value combinations.  Is the `value` for an estimate with a given `action_size`/ `DQN_type` always constant?  Did you try `capsize=0`?

Comment: @JohanC It was the capsize. Still, it doesn't explain why I get no confidence interval? By errors in your original comment, do you mean the upper and lower bounds?

EDIT: Okay I just zoomed in, way in, and it turns out (as you may have tried to tell me,) that the confidence interval simply is so tiny, that it appears as a single line.

If you post a summarized comment as an answer I can confirm it :)